# How can i re rendered reactjs component

Tags: reactjs

How can I update my state value inside child component in this property `{this.state.username}` using of this function `this.messageSubmit` and how can I re-render the child render for displaying changed state values. Please help me anyone how can I update my state value inside and chat box because I'm new to **reactjs**

This is my child component  `chatting.js`

```
    import React from "react";
    export class Chatting extends  React.Component{

    constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state={
        username: 'shiva'
      }
     this.messageSubmit=this.messageSubmit.bind(this);
      this.messageTextBox=this.messageTextBox.bind(this);
    }
         messageTextBox(event){
    this.setState=({
      username :event.target.value
    })

    }

    messageSubmit(){
    console.log(this.setState.username);
    }
      render(){
        return(
    <div>

    <div className="chat-decription">

    <div className="rt">


    <div className="talk-bubble tri-right btm-right">

      <div className="talktext">
        <p>Flush to the bottom right. Uses .btm-right only.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div className="fl">

    <div className="talk-bubble tri-right btm-right">

      <div className="talktext">
        <p>Flush to the bottom right. Uses .btm-right only.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div className="rt">

    <div className="talk-bubble tri-right btm-right">

      <div className="talktext">
        <p>  {this.setState.username}</p>

      </div>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div className="fl">

    <div className="talk-bubble tri-right btm-right">

      <div className="talktext">
        <p>Flush to the bottom right. Uses .btm-right only.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
        </div>
    <div className="chat-textfiled">
    <input type="text" className="form-control text-form" onChange={this.messageTextBox}/>
    <input type="button" value="submit" onClick={this.messageSubmit}/>

    </div>
    </div>

        )
      }
    }
```

This is my parent class

```
import React from "react";
import {render} from "react-dom";
import {Default} from "./component/Default";
import {Chatting} from "./component/Chatting";
import {BrowserRouter as Router,Route,Link,Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
// import Background from '../images/person_img.png';


class App extends React.Component{
constructor(){
  super();

}
  render(){
return(
  <Router>
                 <div className="container">
                 <div className="container-top">
                    <div className="col-lg-4 leftmenu-contact-bg">
                    <div className="searchbox">
                  <div className="textbox-bg">
                <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Search"/>
                  </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="ex1">
                    <a href="/chattting">
                    <div className="left-list">
                    <div  className="left-img"><i className="material-icons icon-color">person</i></div>
                    <div className="right-content">dgfg</div>
                </div>
                </a>

         </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-lg-8 row">
                    <Switch>
                   <Route exact path='/' component={Default} />
                   <Route exact path='/chattting' component={Chatting} />

                </Switch>
                    </div>


                 </div>
                 </div>
              </Router>



);
  }
}
render(<App/>,document.getElementById('app'));
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`setState` is a function.

You should write:

```
this.setState({
  username: event.target.value
});
```

Also, instead of

```
console.log(this.setState.username);
```

You should write

```
console.log(this.state.username);
```

And, again, instead of:

```
<p>{this.setState.username}</p>
```

You should write

```
<p>{this.state.username}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the syntax corrections by @Rahamin, couple of pointers to your code -

1. Calling `setState` in the render function directly shouldn't be used, as it'll go into an infinite recursive function call stack. You'll probably be thrown an error of `Maximum update depth exceeded`.
2. Also, using `console.log`directly in the function that sets the state won't give you the desired output as they are queued and updated. It's best to include such `console.log` statements in the render itself.
3. Lastly, please post questions with good formatted code :)